# Vector Projection as Vector Shrinking

Tags: linear-algebra

My understanding is that if you were to shrink a vector, by dividing it, you would get a new vector in the same direction with a shorter length. When I think about vector projection, it seems similar in that you are discovering a new, shrunken vector, a result of projecting vector 1 onto vector 2.

In other words, if the following two are equivalent:

projection = $v_2$ * $\frac{v_1 \cdot v_2}{\| v_2\|^2}$

projection = $v_2$ / $\frac{v_1 \cdot v_2}{\| v_2\|^2}^{-1}$

would it be fair to think of the term "$\frac{v_1 \cdot v_2}{\| v_2\|^2}$" as a vector operation that shrinks or grows a vector to produce a projection relative to another vector?

If so, could anyone give a somewhat intuitive explanation of why this is? Why does the dot product divided by the squared norm produce a scalar that produces a projection?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question here. Certainly, the projection of $v_1$ onto $v_2$ will have to be parallel to $v_2$, and hence a scalar multiple of $v_2$. If $v_1$ is longer than $v_2$, then this may not "shrink" the vector $v_2$ though.

Comment: Why does the dot product divided by the squared norm produce a scalar that produces a projection?

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out that a projection will of course be parallel, and thus a scalar multiple.

Comment: Associate each factor of $\lVert v_2\rVert^{-1}$ with each instance of $v_2$ in your formula. Now, what is $v_2/\lVert v_2\rVert$?

Comment: That leaves the unit vector for $v_2$ multiplied by the unit vector for $v_1 \cdot v_2$.  Maybe I'm missing the significance of the unit vector?